# SQL Server will not choose optimal index for query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to optimize a SQL Server query created from a COTS application. Therefore, I cannot change the SQL query generated and have to rely completely on the SQL Server query optimizer.

The query generated looks like this (I'm sorry for the messed up SQL. It is generated by the application and I cannot impact it):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    t_02.puid, t_02.pac4_itemId 
FROM 
    PWORKSPACEOBJECT t_01, PAC4_DESIGNSOLREVISION t_02 
WHERE 
    ( ( ( ( t_01.pactive_seq != 0 ) AND 
          ( t_01.pdate_released > CONVERT(datetime, '2011-12-31 23:00:00', 120) ) 
        ) 
        AND t_02.puid IN ( ( ( (SELECT t_03.puid 
                                FROM PAC4_DESIGNSOLREVISION t_03 
                                WHERE  UPPER(t_03.pac4_itemId)  LIKE  UPPER( '%0000%' )
UNION ALL
SELECT t_05.puid FROM PWORKSPACEOBJECT t_04 , PAC4_DESIGNSOLREVISION t_05 WHERE (  UPPER(t_04.pobject_name)  LIKE  UPPER( '%0000%' )  AND ( t_04.puid = t_05.puid ) ) )
UNION ALL
SELECT t_06.puid FROM PAC4_DESIGNSOLREVISION t_06 , PITEMREVISION t_07 WHERE (  UPPER(t_07.pitem_revision_id)  LIKE  UPPER( '%0000%' )  AND ( t_06.puid = t_07.puid ) ) )
UNION ALL
SELECT t_09.puid FROM PWORKSPACEOBJECT t_08 , PAC4_DESIGNSOLREVISION t_09 WHERE (  UPPER(t_08.pobject_type)  LIKE  UPPER( '%0000%' )  AND ( t_08.puid = t_09.puid ) ) )  ) ) AND ( t_01.puid = t_02.puid ) )
```

This query takes 9 seconds to execute.

I created a new index with the following statement:

```
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [AC_ItemId] ON [dbo].[PAC4_DESIGNSOLREVISION] 
    (
        [pac4_itemId] ASC
    )
    INCLUDE ( [puid]) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
```

After that I tested the same query and the optimizer did not choose the index. It preferred the clustered index instead. Query still takes 9 seconds to complete.

I then hinted the query to use my new index using "with (index(AC_ItemId))":

```
SELECT  DISTINCT t_02.puid, t_02.pac4_itemId FROM PWORKSPACEOBJECT t_01 , PAC4_DESIGNSOLREVISION t_02 WHERE ( ( ( ( t_01.pactive_seq != 0 ) AND ( t_01.pdate_released > CONVERT(datetime, '2011-12-31 23:00:00', 120) ) ) AND t_02.puid IN  (  (  (  ( SELECT t_03.puid FROM PAC4_DESIGNSOLREVISION t_03 **with (index(AC_ItemId))** WHERE  UPPER(t_03.pac4_itemId)  LIKE  UPPER( '%0000%' )
UNION ALL
SELECT t_05.puid FROM PWORKSPACEOBJECT t_04 , PAC4_DESIGNSOLREVISION t_05 WHERE (  UPPER(t_04.pobject_name)  LIKE  UPPER( '%0000%' )  AND ( t_04.puid = t_05.puid ) ) )
UNION ALL
SELECT t_06.puid FROM PAC4_DESIGNSOLREVISION t_06 , PITEMREVISION t_07 with (index(AC_RevId)) WHERE (  UPPER(t_07.pitem_revision_id)  LIKE  UPPER( '%0000%' )  AND ( t_06.puid = t_07.puid ) ) )
UNION ALL
SELECT t_09.puid FROM PWORKSPACEOBJECT t_08 , PAC4_DESIGNSOLREVISION t_09 WHERE (  UPPER(t_08.pobject_type)  LIKE  UPPER( '%0000%' )  AND ( t_08.puid = t_09.puid ) ) )  ) ) AND ( t_01.puid = t_02.puid ) )
```

With this addition the query takes 0 seconds to execute.

How do I tell the SQL server optimizer to choose this index when the query is run from a COTS application where I cannot change the queries generated?

**Update 1:**

If I run the sub-SQL statement standalone the optimizer chooses the non-clustered index. The problem occurs when sub-SQL is put in context of the full SQL statement.

This is the sub-SQL referred to:

```
SELECT t_03.puid 
FROM PAC4_DESIGNSOLREVISION t_03 
WHERE UPPER(t_03.pac4_itemId) LIKE UPPER('%0000%')
```

Comment: I'm curious how fast the original query is if you remove the UPPER call from `UPPER(t_03.pac4_itemId)`, without the index hint.

Comment: @hatchet I tried removing the upper functions but no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a composite index that contains all or most of the fields that your referencing, until the optimizer decides that is the appropriate index to use.

Comment: AC_ItemId index has the pac4_itemId column in index and it includes the puid column. Those are all the columns referenced from the PAC4_DESIGNSOLREVISION. I also tried putting both pac4_itemId and puid in a composite index, but it didn't impact the outcome. Have I understood you correctly?

Comment: I was just rereading the query and it seems like you do have all the fields.  It may be that including the pac4_ItemId onto the puid index would get it to find it.  I noticed that the modified query also includes the hint: with (index(AC_RevId))  which I'm assuming was also added.  Is it correctly selecting this index without the hint?

Comment: No, this is the issue. Without the hint it is not picking my index. The question is how I manage SQL server to pick the optimal index without hinting.

Comment: I did as you said. I dropped the clustered index that was on puid only. Then I created a new clustered index with puid and ac4_itemId columns. The query now runs fast.

Comment: That's great.  Any chance you could accept my answer?